# Portable way to check if expression compiles

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I need a portable way to define a template class which checks validity of some expression on its parameter. Ideally it should work identically in MSVC 2013+, Clang 3.1+ and GCC 4.8+.

Usage example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int Back() {return 5;}
};
static_assert(HasBack<MyStruct>::value, "Back must exist!");
```

I tried this code:

```
template<typename T, typename dummy=void> struct HasBack: std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct HasBack<T, void_t<decltype(declval<T>().Back())>>: std::true_type {};
```

It works in clang, but doesn't work in Visual Studio. Especially for it I wrote another implementation using compiler extensions:

```
template<typename T> struct HasBack
{
    __if_exists(void_t<decltype(declval<T>().Back())>) {enum {value=1};}
    __if_not_exists(void_t<decltype(declval<T>().Back())>) {enum {value=0};}
};
```

It compiles and works in Visual Studio 2013+ but it fully disables IntelliSense in any project that includes this code. Is there workarounds for these problems or maybe there is some different way to do expression check, that works for all compilers?

Comment: The title is very different than the question you ask in the last paragraph. Please fix the title.

Comment: Isn't `void_t` which should be written in some way to be portable across compiler for SFINAE ?

Comment: Oh, how we must all be looking forward to concepts making it into the language...  It would be so much easier to be able to write `template <typename T> concept bool HasBack = requires(T x) { { x.Back() }; };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code compile with my g++ (4.9.2) and my clang++ (3.5).

Sorry but I don't have a MSVC so I'm not sure it's good for you.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct HasBack
 {
   template<typename U>
      static decltype(std::declval<U>().Back(), std::true_type{}) func (std::remove_reference_t<U>*); 

   template<typename U>    
      static std::false_type func (...);

   using  type = decltype(func<T>(nullptr));

   static constexpr bool value { type::value };
 };

struct MyStruct
 { int Back() {return 5;} };

static_assert(true  == HasBack<MyStruct>::value, "yes");
static_assert(false == HasBack<int>::value,      "no");

int main ()
 { return 0; }
```

I hope this helps and sorry for my bad English.

**--- EDIT ---**

Modified example (adding use of `std::declval`) according the correction from aschepler (thanks!)

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Following the PaulMcKenzie's suggestions, I've compiled the example in [rextester](http://www.rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual); seems to work with VS 2015 too.

**--- EDIT 3 ---**

Modified according the GLmonster's osservation (`std::remove_reference<U>*` instead `U*` as argument of first version of `func()`.

Comment: `U().Back()` doesn't work if `U` is not default-constructible.  This is the purpose of `std::declval`.

Comment: @aschepler - thanks! I didn't know (I'm learning C++11 but I suppose it's too much for me); I ever used this solution with default-contructible classes. Please, could you see if now is correct?

Comment: @max66 If you don't have VS 2015, you can always go to this [online compiler that supports VC 2015](http://www.rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual)

Comment: I found a problem. This solution doesn't work with references because `func` will take pointer to reference in implementation. But it can be fixed by replacing `U*` with `std::remove_reference_t<U>*`.

Comment: @GLmonster - thanks; corrected the answer according it.

Answer (score 1):

If you take implementation of [std::experimental::is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
// The "safer" way for
// template<typename... Ts> using void_t = void;
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

struct nonesuch {
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

namespace detail {
template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
          template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector {
  using value_t = std::false_type;
  using type = Default;
};

template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
  using value_t = std::true_type;
  using type = Op<Args...>;
};

} // namespace detail

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;
```

Then, you just have to write:

```
template <typename T>
using back_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().Back());

template <typename T>
using HasBack = is_detected<back_t, T>;
```

Comment: I tried it, but it also didn't work in Visual Studio. I also tried implementation with workaround for msvc 2015, which I found from one of answers here but it didn't work with msvc 2013.

Comment: I tried it with gcc/clang and msvc2015 with success, sad it doesn't work with msvc2013 :/